# Docker-compose.yml Volummes: and -mount command not the same results

Tags: docker-compose

I have been searching for over a week on this issue with no solution.
I am trying to mount a volume from the docker-compose.yml
Here is my directory structure:

```
-docker-compose.yml
-api
  -dockerfile
-frontend
  -dockerfile
-models
```

I have want the models shared between the api service, and the frontend service. first I attempt to get the models into the container. In the container's /usr/src/models directory along with all of its contents. This command works GREAT

```
docker run -it --mount src="$(pwd)/models",target=/usr/src/models,type=bind -p 3000:3000 website_api
```

and an important thing to note is that it produces this, when I inspect the docker container in VS code:
website_api.json:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/website/models",
                "Target": "/usr/src/models"
            }
        ],
```

This is inside of the json file with lots of other stuff.
however, when I run my docker-compose, that is setup like so:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    api:
        container_name: api
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./api/dockerfile
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
            - "3001:3001"
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: "./models"
              target: "/usr/src/models"
```

the mounts path in the json file displays as so:

```
"Mounts": [],
```

and the /usr/src/models directory in my container is empty...

So these two things do not do the same thing as I seemed to believe before.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong in my docker-compose.yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
tree
.
├── api
│   └── dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
└── models
    └── someFile
```

```
cat docker-compose.yml 
version: "3.8"
services:
    api:
        container_name: api
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./api/dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./models:/usr/src/models
```

`docker-compose up -d`

```
docker exec 5ea0c49003f6 sh -c "ls -la /usr/src/models"
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 Aug  3 20:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug  3 20:15 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000    0 Aug  3 20:09 someFile
```

```
docker container inspect --format '{{.Mounts}}' 5ea0c49003f6
[{bind  /home/neo/so-playground/mounts-63236400/models /usr/src/models  rw true rprivate}]
```

Comment: I have tried this before, The issue is that without the "bind" then the models folder is empty inside of the container. Almost like it creates the models inside of /usr/src/ but then can't see the host's models directory's content
Also when I use inspect to see the website_api.json, I see:
"Volumes": null,
and also
"Models": []

Comment: I have a file inside that directory on the host and I can access it in the container. Check the `docker exec 5ea0c49003f6 sh -c "ls -la /usr/src/models"` that I execute inside the container. Am I missing something?

Comment: Starting the docker container with docker-compose up -d and the change to Volumes that you suggested works, however when starting the docker container from the VS Code extension by right clicking and hitting start does not work... Would you know why????

Comment: Perhaps the VS Code extension is issuing a simple `docker run ` omitting the `-v`?

Comment: It appears so, I found what VS Code is running, the command is: docker run --rm -d  -p 3000:3000/tcp -p 3001:3001/tcp website_api:latest

Comment: I don't have VS code installed on this machine(I am in hardcore mode using vim atm :))), but I suppose you can specify the volumes somehow. In the same place where you specified the publish `-p 3000:3000` option, try to add `-v <src>:<dst>`